# clearing radio button after form submission react native

Tags: react-native

```
react-native-simple-radio-button
```

i have a simple form with radio buttons
i want to clear the form after submission
but it is not getting cleared this is weird

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import RadioForm, { RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel } from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      ages: [
        {key:1,label:20},
        {key:2,label:30},
        {key:3,label:40},
      ],

      initialRadioPos: -1
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            marginTop: 10,
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
          }}>
            <RadioForm
              radio_props={this.state.ages}
              initial={this.state.initialRadioPos}
              formHorizontal={false}
              labelHorizontal={true}
              buttonColor={this.state.switched ? '#673AB7' : '#A9A9A9'}
              selectedButtonColor={this.state.switched ? '#673AB7' : '#A9A9A9'}
              onPress={currentAge => {
                this.setState({ currentAge });
              }}
            />
            <Button title="submit" onPress={()=>this.clear()}/>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  clear = () =>{
    this.setState({
      initialRadioPos:-1
    })
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

and here is the code on snack you can check it
https://snack.expo.io/@andreh111/aW5zYW

i am setting the initialRadioPos to -1 on button press but nothing happens but i think the code logic is correct ... so where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't changed the value of the `initialRadioPos` so when you call setState it checks for any changes, notices that it is the same and it doesn't re-render the component.

You could do the following to make the component re-render. It is a little *hacky* but it will work. By setting the key property on the RadioForm to a value in state, and updating that value when you clear it, it should re-render the form.

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import RadioForm, { RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel } from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      ages: [
        {key:1,label:20},
        {key:2,label:30},
        {key:3,label:40},
      ],

      initialRadioPos: -1,
      formKey: 0 // set an initial key here
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            marginTop: 10,
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
          }}>
            <RadioForm
              key={this.state.formKey} // set the key prop to the value in state
              radio_props={this.state.ages}
              initial={this.state.initialRadioPos}
              formHorizontal={false}
              labelHorizontal={true}
              buttonColor={this.state.switched ? '#673AB7' : '#A9A9A9'}
              selectedButtonColor={this.state.switched ? '#673AB7' : '#A9A9A9'}
              onPress={currentAge => {
                this.setState({ currentAge });
              }}
            />
            <Button title="submit" onPress={()=>this.clear()}/>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  clear = () =>{
    this.setState({
      formKey: Math.random() // update the key 
    })
  }
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/HJXSxkGQV

Comment: oh working like a charm thank you ... if you can give me 1+ on the question